# Trying to delete using Node.js Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

```
app.delete("/tm/v1/tasks", (req,res) => {
      Task.findOneAndDelete(req.body.id, (err, car) => {
        if (err){
          res.status(500).json({msg: error});
        }
      res.status(200).json({tasks});
      })
});
```

The above isn't working and is giving an error 404. any ideas?

Comment: `(2)` Can you share the error ? `(1)` Are you sure there is a Task document instance with that ID ?

Comment: Hi Marcus, can you please share more code and the request? this will help us to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- please check if you have are using correct url
- we can add body to delete request in postman or curl but its not possible to pass body in javascript, dart (http package), etc.
- you can rewrite function as

```
app.post('/tm/v1/delete-tasks', (req, res) => {
    // write your code here...
});
```